# Drupal: phptemplate_menu_tree not firing in template.php

Tags: drupal, themes

I'm using drupal 6.x with the garland theme. I went into the garland theme directory and have attempted to use the garland_menu_tree override to alter the ul container within the template.php file.

However, it's not firing. I have even put in an echo to see if the method is being called and it isn't.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

clearing the cache worked